# Is there a .NET library for the adobe flex textflow XML format

Tags: .net, apache-flex, textflow

I am sending some data into a system,from a .NET system, that uses the Adobe TextFlow format to render the output,

Is there a .NET Library that can help me out.

for reference the initial tag looks something like this.

```
<TextFlow columnCount="inherit" columnGap="inherit" columnWidth="inherit" direction="ltr" 
 fontLookup="embeddedCFF" lineBreak="inherit" paddingBottom="inherit" paddingLeft="inherit" 
 paddingRight="inherit" paddingTop="inherit" renderingMode="cff" verticalAlign="inherit" 
 whiteSpaceCollapse="preserve" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008">
```

Comment: How much control do you have over the flex app?  Flex has some capabilities to translate from XML or HTML to TextFlow format...it'll be easier to create one of those if your display system allows this.

Comment: We have no control, It is a purchased app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately there aren't any .NET libraries to output Adobe TextFlow markup.

However, since the TextFlow format is just a type of XML, you can use the .NET XML capabilities to create the markup.

Comment: The XML structure was not very complex and turned out fairly easy todo.